# Solving the diffusion equation in a ball with Neumann BC

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I was hoping to ask for finding $\lambda_n$ in the following problem, I need to jog my memory as to how to solve these using fourier series. I am only interested in $\lambda_n$ as these terms will represent my decay rates.

Suppose we have a ball, radius $r_0$, with the diffusion equation
$$\frac{\partial c(r,t)}{\partial t} = 
\frac{D}{r^2} 
\frac{\partial }{\partial r}
\left(
r^2
\frac{\partial }{\partial r}
c(r,t)
\right),
\quad r\in[0,r_0],t\geq 0$$

with neumann boundary conditions
$$
D\frac{\partial c}{\partial r} = -pc
,\quad \text{on}\ \ r=r_0
$$

with initial conditions
$$c(r,0)=
\begin{cases}
c_0 & r\in[0,R] \\
0 & r\in(R,r_0]
\end{cases}$$

where $D,p>0$.

If we let
$$c = R(r)T(t)$$

then we find 
$$
\frac{1}{D}\frac{T'}{T} = 
\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial r^2}
+
\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial r^2} = -\lambda^2
$$

Therefore
$T(t)=\exp(-D \lambda^2 t)$. I'm interested in describing the half-life of this system by examining the decay rates of the series solution to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last displayed equation is wrong. You get
$$r^2R''+2rR'+\lambda^2r^2R=0\ .$$
Introduce a new unknown function $Q(r):=r\>R(r)$. You then obtain $Q'=R+rR'$, $Q''=2R'+rR''$ and therefore
$$r(Q''+\lambda^2 Q)=r^2R''+2rR'+\lambda^2 r^2R=0\ .$$
It follows that
$$Q(r)=a\cos(\lambda r)+b\sin(\lambda r)\ .$$
Since $R(r)={1\over r}Q(r)$ one necessarily has $a=0$, so that we are left with $R(r)={1\over r}\sin(\lambda r)$. We now have to determine the $\lambda$s for which the boundary condition
$$D\>R'(r_0)=-p\>R(r_0)\tag{1}$$
is fulfilled. To this end we compute
$$R'(r)=-{1\over r^2}\sin(\lambda r)+{\lambda\over r}\cos(\lambda r)\ .$$
Plugging this and $R(r)$ into $(1)$ we obtain the transcendental equation (typical for this kind of problem)
$$\tan\alpha={D\over D-r_0p}\>\alpha$$for the dimensionless unknown $\alpha:=\lambda r_0$. Now determine numerically the smallest positive solution of this equation, and you are done.

Comment: Thank you for this! Extremely helpful, would you be able to expand on how to find the lambda values? As this is what I am most interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the update! This is really helpful. So the smallest +ve solution for $\lambda$ will give the power of the dominant exponential, and hence the half-life?

Comment: Also, why may we not consider -ve lambda values?

Comment: Replacing a $\lambda$ by its negative just multiplies the corresponding  "basis function" $R_\lambda(r)$ by $-1$, hence gives nothing new.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I very much appreciate it.